# Can wifi network administrators see if you are using a proxy?

Tags: wifi, vpn, proxy

A friend of mine wants to use a Proxy on his home computer because his parents have blocked many games and social media services. My question is, if he is using a Proxy, will his parents be able to see that he is using a Proxy?

Comment: TOR might be an option.  It looks like standard SSL/TLS traffic.  Unless his parents check the IP addresses that he connects to (to see if they are TOR entry nodes), it won't look suspicious.  BTW, nice username.  Do you know Phil McCrackin?

Comment: You probably want to edit your question to point out his parent works in cybersecurity. Trying to hide from the average person vs people who work in this field requires entirely different toolkits.

Comment: @Martheen it doesn't matter if the parent knows about proxies, it doesn't fundamentally change the question. We can't know what the knowledge level is or what the specific monitoring capability allows. The fundamental facts, however, are not dependent on those things.

Answer (score 2):

If your friend is using a proxy, all the requests will look as requests towards the IP of the proxy. Depending on your friend's parents' knowledge of networks, they might find that as a suspicious behavior. In normal cases where the average parents don't know much about proxies, there should not be any problem.

Comment: Thank you, sadly in his case one of his parents is in the cybersecurity business, so he is probably out of luck.